# Update a column data w.r.t values in other columns regex match in dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a data frame of rows of more than 1,000,000 and 15 columns.
I have to make new columns and assign the value to the columns w.r.t the other string values in the other columns via matching them either with regex or exact character match.

For example, if a column called FIle path is there. I have to make a column as a feature that will be assigned values with the input of the folder path (Full | partial) and match it with the file path and update the feature column.

I thought about using the iteration with for loop but it is so much time taking and while using pandas for this I think iterating would consume more time if looping components increase in the future.
Is there an efficient way for the pandas to do this type of operation
Please help me with this.

Example:
I have a df as:

```
| ID       | File           |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | SWE_Toot       |
| 2        | SWE_Thun       |
| 3        | IDH_Toet       |
| 4        | SDF_Then       |
| 5        | SWE_Toot       |
| 6        | SWE_Thun       |
| 7        | SEH_Toot       |
| 8        | SFD_Thun       |
```

I will get components in other tables as

```
| ID       | File           |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Software | */SWE_Toot/*.h |
|          |*/IDH_Toet/*.c  |
|          |*/SFD_Toto/*.c  |
```

second as:

```
| ID       | File           |
| -------- | -------------- |
| Wire     | */SDF_Then/*.h |
|          |*/SFD_Thun/*.c  |
|          |*/SFD_Toto/*.c  |
```

etc., will me around like 1000000 files and 278 components are received

I want as

```
| ID       | File           |Component|
| -------- | -------------- |---------|
| 1        | SWE_Toot       |Software |
| 2        | SWE_Thun       |Other    |
| 3        | IDH_Toet       |Software |
| 4        | SDF_Then       |Wire     |
| 5        | SWE_Toto       |Various  |
| 6        | SWE_Thun       |Other    |
| 7        | SEH_Toto       |Various  |
| 8        | SFD_Thun       |Wire     |
```

Other - will be filled at last once all the fields and regex are checked and do not belong to any component.

Various - It may belong to more than one (or) we can give a list of components it belong to.

I was able to read the components tables and create a regex and if I want to create the component column then I have to write for loops for all the 278 columns and I have to loop the same table with the component.

Is there a way to do this with the pandas easier

Because the date will be very large

Comment: 1) Could you provide a minimal **complete** example? It is not clear wher 'Other' and 'Various' strings in the desired output came from. 2) What are the contents of your files? How are they used? 3) What happens if a row corresponds to several files?

Comment: 1. I have provided other and various meanings in the question.
2. As in first I will have a raw excel file where df will read which will consist of a filename or full file path and the other one is a component file where I will get regex | file path | filename.
3. I didn't understand this. But as I mention the filename may belong to different columns and so either add both of them in it or add them as various is my plan.
I made the edit I gave two component DF.